# Sony Camera Remote API SDK for Bluetooth

Tags: api, bluetooth, camera, sony

I am wondering if it's possible to use the ***Sony Sony Camera Remote API beta SDK*** / AddOn SDK / Smart Extension API to control action cameras functionality by my application side via **BlueTooth** (no Wi-Fi).

My goal is to write an extension which will mainly:

- **Mandatory**: start and stop video saving on camera internal memory
- Optional: , insert allarms, set video acquisition parameters, ecc.

Does anyone have:

- the information if this SDK is the right choice to control this type of Sony device
- if it's possible to reach my described goal with it or if there are any impossibilities
- other related information or special requirements for controlling Sony cameras via bluetooth.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will only be able to use Wifi to control cameras with the camera remote API.